# Enviar un textview recibido

Tags: javascript, android, paypal

El caso es que envié un `TextView` desde un `Fragment` a una actividad.
Y ese `TextView` que ya esta dentro y me aparece en la actividad quiero mandar como monto total a pagar de Paypal
pero no me funciona. Utilizo Paypal sdk

**xml activity_paypal**

```
public class PaypalActivity extends  AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //The views
    Button buttonPay;
    TextView mtotal;

    //Payment Amount
    private String paymentAmount;


    //Paypal intent request code to track onActivityResult method
    public static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 123;


    //Paypal Configuration Object
    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            // Start with mock environment.  When ready, switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(PayPalConfig.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);

        String total = getIntent().getExtras().getString("total");
        TextView mtotal =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        mtotal.setText(total);


        buttonPay.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startService(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void getPayment() {
        //Getting the amount from editText

        paymentAmount = mtotal.getText().toString();

        //Creating a paypalpayment
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Total",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        //Creating Paypal Payment activity intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

        //putting the paypal configuration to the intent
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        //Puting paypal payment to the intent
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

        //Starting the intent activity for result
        //the request code will be used on the method onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //If the result is from paypal
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {

            //If the result is OK i.e. user has not canceled the payment
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Getting the payment confirmation
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

                //if confirmation is not null
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        //Getting the payment details
                        String paymentDetails = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        Log.i("paymentExample", paymentDetails);

                        //Starting a new activity for the payment details and also putting the payment details with intent
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
                                .putExtra("PaymentAmount", paymentAmount));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getPayment();
    }
}
```

Comment: He suprimido el texto en Inglés ya que el idioma oficial de [es.so] es el español. Sería bueno que hicieras el [tour] y que te pasaras por [ask] para aprender a hacer una buena pregunta.

Comment: Hola GJ, bienvenida, es **muy importante** revises los documentos que te indica Pikoh!. En cuanto a tu pregunta lo que deseas ya lo realiza el método getPayment(), solo mandalo llamar.

Answer (score 2):

El texto de tu TextView `mtotal` no se envia, porque estas declarando dos variable `mtotal`. Una al inicio de la clase y otra en el `onCreate()`. La variable que declaras al principio de la clase es nula, ya que no la estas inicializando y por eso al obtener su valor en el metodo `getPayment()`, no obtienes nada. La variable que inicializas y a la que le asignas un valor, es a la que esta declarada dentro del `onCreate()`, pero esta variable no la puedes usar fuera del `onCreate()`, ya que es una variable del metodo.

Para solucionar tu problema tienes que inicializar en el `onCreate()` la variable que declaras al principio de la clase.

```
public class PaypalActivity extends  AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //The views
    TextView mtotal;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);

        String total = getIntent().getExtras().getString("total");

        // Al eliminar TextView de la variable mtotal, se inicializa la variable 
        // que declaraste al inicio de la clase, en vez de crear una variable nueva.
        mtotal =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);

        mtotal.setText(total);

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: gracias pero no me ha servido, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Has probado introduciendo el valor a enviar directamente:

 `PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1000.00"), "USD", "Total",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);`

Comment: Introduciendo el valor me funciona, pero en mi caso es una app de compras y necesito capturar el valor del textview (que viene siendo el precio de los productos)

Comment: Estas seguro de estar recibiendo el valor desde el fragment?

Comment: Sii! sin el codigo de paypal recibe el valor perfectamente, pero con el codigo ya no, y no se como configurarlo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está aquí:

```
 PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Total",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

a la hora de parsear un string a un decimal no es necesario hacer "String.valueOf(paymentAmount)" ya que paymentAmount ya es un String. Tienes que buscar la forma correcta de parsear un String a un BigDecimal. 
[String to BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752616/5854328)

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente en lo que comentas,

> El caso es que envié un TextView desde un Fragment a una actividad.
>   en realidad no se envia un `TextView`, se envía el valor que contiene:

Tu ya recibes el valor en tu `Activity` y lo estas agregando a tu `TextView`, pero este mismo valor lo puedes enviar en el Intent que realiza el pago, esto lo tienes ya realizado dentro de `getPayment()` :

```
 private void getPayment() {
        //Getting the amount from editText

        paymentAmount = mtotal.getText().toString(); //Obtiene valor del TextView.

        //Creating a paypalpayment
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Total",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        //Creating Paypal Payment activity intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

        //putting the paypal configuration to the intent
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        //Puting paypal payment to the intent
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

        //Starting the intent activity for result
        //the request code will be used on the method onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Simplemente tienes que llamar este método!

---

Veo que actualmente el método que realiza el pago se llama al dar clic desde alguna vista definida en tu archivo `activity_paypal.xml` que tiene la propiedad `android:onClick="onClick"`, revisa cual es esa vista:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getPayment();
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, no he entendido muy bien la solución. Entonces en el OnCreate no hace falta que obtenga el valor de la textView ya que el el getPayment ya lo hace. ? Puedes aclararme la duda

Comment: En onCreate estas recibiendo el valor y lo agregas a tu TextView, en getPayment() obtiene el valor del TextView en esta línea: paymentAmount = mtotal.getText().toString();   y mandas el monto total a pagar. Ahora tu define donde necesitas llamar getPayment().